# How to link libconfig++ with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

I've tried to link libconifg with CMake for a project but it seems that I cannot link it properly :

> fatal error: 'libconfig.h++' file not found
> #include <libconfig.h++>

so I tried different method to make it happens but nothing seems to work (I'm on a mac M1 system)

Here are all the method I've tried :

```
# Find the 'libconfig' library and store its location in the 'libconfig' variable.
find_library(libconfig libconfig)

# Include the FetchContent module to fetch and manage external projects.
include(FetchContent)

# Declare an external project 'config++' and specify how to fetch it from a Git repository.
FetchContent_Declare(config++
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/hyperrealm/libconfig.git
    GIT_TAG v1.7.3)

# Fetch and make the 'config++' external project available for use.
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(config++)

# Find and configure the 'libconfig' package that was fetched using FetchContent.
find_package(libconfig CONFIG REQUIRED)

# Find the directory containing the 'libconfig.h' header file and store its path.
find_path(LIB_LIB_DIR libconfig.h)

# Find the 'libconfig' library file and store its path.
find_library(LIB_LIB_LIBRARY NAMES libconfig)

# Find the 'libconfig++' library file and store its path.
find_library(LIBCONFIGPP_LOCATION libconfig++)

# Find the 'libconfig' library file again and store its path.
find_library(LIBCONFIG_LOCATION libconfig)
```

And when it comes to link the libraries :

target_link_libraries(MyProject common_lib sfml-graphics sfml-audio sfml-window sfml-system fftw config++) (I use these other libraries for my project)

Comment: You don't seem to be adding the header file include path for the compiler to find the header files.

Comment: I added the include path for the compiler right here :

add_executable(MyProject
        include/SpritePool.hpp
        my other source files here
)

Comment: You need to use the [`target_include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html) to add the paths to the header files, if they are not in a standard location (like for modules that you download and build).

Comment: CMake is not `make`, and it does not necessarily even *use* `make` or makefiles.  Tags edited.